# How to trigger azure Function in same App

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure function project with two functions. One which is triggered by a timer and one that is triggered by HTTP. How to I trigger the http manually from code? I know I can trigger it using the URL, but the URL will change when the function is deployed.

Comment: I suppose only the hostname in the url changes based on the environment you are targeting. Route or path to the function itself should not change usually. So, can you not make the hostname configurable and populate that in the deployment process (assuming you have a CI/CD pipeline)?

Comment: I dont really have a CL/CD pipeline, but I can work around that. I guess that would be the easiest way. I assumed there would be a helper function to call other functions in the same app, but I am probably mistaken.

Comment: Not the most elegant but you can simply call the other function as a normal function if it is in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use of the HTTP client if the intention is to call from the code only.

```html
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
    var result = await client.GetAsync("");
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.Info(resultContent);
}
```

2) Other option is use [Durable Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension#durable-functions), particularly [Function Chaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence)

Comment: Durable functions seems to be the right way for my case